# SSMTP Delivery Error

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

This is my first post and I don't know how to introduce, so I'm just going to jump right in.

So every hour I have cron run a script which outputs a table, and I wanted this delivered as a notification to my smartphone via the Pushover Email Gateway, in which an email sent to a specific @pomail.net email is automatically turned into a notification and shown on my phone.

Ok, so I had already set up the cron script, then I moved to the notification, following the email alerts guide by HowToGeek (Apparently I have too many links)

I found some of the settings confusing, but, after following several error fixes online, such as enabling insecure apps in gmail and adding a line to the end of "/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf", I thought I had it working when "echo "Test message from Linux server using ssmtp" | sudo ssmtp -vvv personalemail@gmail.com" succeeded in sending an email.

I modified the config file to this (without parentheses):
    root=(my email id)@pomail.net (the email to send to)
    mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
    hostname=localhost
    AuthUser=raspberrypinotify@gmail.com (my pi email to sent the email from)
    AuthPass=password
    FromLineOverride=YES
    UseSTARTTLS=YES
    TLS_CA_File=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

And the revaliases file to this:
    root:raspberrypinotify@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
(not my actual email)

However, now every hour (the script runs in cron every hour) I receive an email on my raspberrypinotify@gmail.com account from mailer-daemon@googlemail.com inside a conversation in which my email sent a email to "pi" with the bcc of "pi" and a body of the desired message. The email from mailer-daemon@googlemail.com has a body of:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
     pi@localhost Technical details of permanent failure: 
DNS Error: 30638252 DNS type 'mx' lookup of localhost 
responded with code NXDOMAIN Domain name not found: 
localhost ----- Original message ----- DKIM-Signature: v=1; 
a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=message-id:from:date:to:subject:mime-version
         :content-transfer-encoding;
        bh=(random letters that I don't think that I should reveal)=;
        b=(more secret random letters)== X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; 
c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
        h=x-gm-message-state:message-id:from:date:to:subject:mime-version
         :content-transfer-encoding;
        bh=(spooky secret letters)=;
        b=(super secret letters)== 
X-Received: by (ip address) with SMTP id (I don't think I should reveal this);
        Wed, 08 Jun 2016 15:00:44 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path: 
<raspberrypinotify@gmail.com> Received: from localhost 
([(my ip)])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id (I don't think I should reveal this)
        for <pi@localhost>
        (version=TLS1 cipher=AES128-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 08 Jun 2016 15:00:43 -0700 (PDT) Message-ID: 
<(another id)@mx.google.com> From: root 
<raspberrypinotify@gmail.com> X-Google-Original-From: 
root (Cron Daemon) Received: by localhost (sSMTP sendmail 
emulation); Wed, 08 Jun 2016 22:00:42 +0000 Date: Wed, 08 
Jun 2016 22:00:42 +0000 To: pi Subject: Cron 
<pi@raspberrypi> /home/pi/speedtest-cron.sh MIME-Version: 
1.0 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh> 
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/pi> X-Cron-Env: 
<PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=pi>
```

Then my original message is shown below the error message

Now I have no clue what this email means, and is probably just telling me that I configured something wrong. Anyway, I would love to have an answer to this annoying problem, even if it's just an explanation of how bad I messed up the config files.

Comment: Tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/51819/how-to-setup-email-alerts-on-linux-using-gmail/